# Site name in header css?

Tags: css, html

I would put the site name in the middle of this header but unfortunately I can not do it, I've tried many combinations but I just can not. I'll post the source

CSS

```
.header {
    background-color:#00B9ED;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    padding-left:auto;
    padding-right:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1000px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

.logo {
    width:150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo img {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
}

.logo:hover {
    height:50px;
    background-color:#A9E2F3;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="image.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

have no idea how can I do? Thanks

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` on your `.logo` would [do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/3JHLY/)

Comment: In any case, it helps if you post a question if you make things as readable as possible (formatting of your code), and check if it's valid code (missing closing brackets, unclosed tags, etc). This helps us help you (and makes it more fun for us to help you as well). Note that you can edit your question to improve it (the edit screen has a great live preview as well).

Comment: John , I think you make a wrong spelling on `margin-right:auto;` of `wrapper` to `margim-right` before edit this question ? Isn't it ?

Comment: I had already tried, but in doing so the image falls down. Try it yourself with an image please. Sorry for my english

Comment: remove `width: 1000px` from `#wrapper`.  It will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Code

```
<style>
.header {
background-color:#00B9ED;
height:50px;
border-bottom:0px;
padding-left:auto;
padding-right:auto;
width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
margin-left:auto;
margim-right:auto;

padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
.logo {
text-align: center;
}
.logo img {
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
}
.logo:hover {
height:50px;
background-color:#A9E2F3;   
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<div class="header">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="logo">
<a>Bhavin<img src="image.png"></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

CSS

```
    #wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        width: 1000px;
    }

.logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="logo">
<a href="#">logo<img src="image.png"  alt="LOGO"/></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to code with standards. You can use `text-align` but it is for align **paragraph** or other **elements with text**. Insted align I would recommend to use `margin:0 auto;width:150px;`.

Here you got [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpiesnikowski/5xsqb/)

Comment: `text-align` is not always just for "_paragraph or other elements with text_". it can used to any element. http://jsfiddle.net/GrtN2/